# Intercept request and modify response

Tags: javascript, http, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a Chrome extension that when the user requests `mysite/file.js` it will replace the `alert('hi')` to `alert('bye')`. I can't figure this out I am new at Chrome Extensions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be better ways to achieve what you need, depending on your use case.

For example, you could inject a content script that overrides `alert` on the page [world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world).

`context.js`

```
const script = document.createElement('script');

script.innerHTML = `
    const originalAlert = window.alert;

    window.alert = (msg) => {
        originalAlert(msg === 'hello' ? 'bye' : msg);
    };
`;

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply (I don't check this ever). That is what I ended up doing :p